# Why can't FLASK_APP find my factory function?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to reconfigure an existing Flask app with an application factory to be installed with `setup.py`.

Currently, with my non-installable package, I use a file called `wsgi.py` and point `FLASK_APP` at that.

```
from example.factory import create_app
app = create_app()
```

```
export FLASK_APP=wsgi.py
flask run
```

However, if I try to point Flask directly at the factory in the installed package, I get`RuntimeError: Failed to find application in module "example.factory"`. I found this pattern in the [examples in the Flask repository](https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr).

```
export FLASK_APP="example.factory:create_app()"
flask run  # doesn't find the app
```

Why does the `wsgi.py` method work while the direct method fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the docs and examples that match the version of Flask that you're using.

You're looking at the tutorial from the master branch. But you're using the current Flask release, which doesn't support detecting app factories yet. You still need to use your current method of pointing at a file that creates the app until 1.0 is released.

Answer (score 10):

I kept my flask application name as `flask.py`.

Changing this to `flaskfile.py` or any other name but not `flask` alone worked for me

Maybe flask is a keyword.

Comment: Looks like, naming the file just "flask.py" will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you actually return the 'app' variable in your create_app.